# How to have command history between RS232 Serial Port and local laptop?

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, firmware, .net-4.8

I was developing a `C# Console app` to interact with firmware on SAS Expander card.

The card was connected via `RS232` Port.

I have already sent a command and had a result on the Console App.

Now I want to have a function to record command.

When I  use `PuTTY` to send command,

I realize that when I press `UpArrow` key, it will show the last command.

Here is `PuTTY`'s result:

before press `UpArrow Key`→

[image]

after press `UpArrow Key`→

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {

                mySerialPort.Write("\r");

            }
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            while (true)
            {
                
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo userResponse = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    List<string> Command = new List<string>();
                    if (userResponse.KeyChar.ToString() == "s")
                    {
                        Command.Add("s");
                        mySerialPort.Write("s");

                    }
                    else if (userResponse.KeyChar.ToString() == "y")
                    {
                        Command.Add("y");
                        mySerialPort.Write("y");

                    }
                    else if (userResponse.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < Command.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Command[i]);

                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Command.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mySerialPort.Write("\r");
                        
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write(indata);
        }

    }

}
```

What the code's result:

[image]

When I press `UpArrow` key twice, the app shows up two space to enter.

That was the second `bp1>` in the picture.

The picture looks like:

[image]

After I press `enter` Key, it comes out `bp1>` again.

I started to send `sys` command and it didn't get response, but it came up a space to enter.

After I press `Enter` and `UpArrow` key again, the `sys` command shows up.

What is the problem with my code?

Is there  another way to improve?

My console App is using `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

Comment: For example, why not incorporate and apply such a project? [mono/LineEditor](https://github.com/mono/LineEditor) It would be nice to buffer the history at the same time as sending normal keystrokes to the device, enter such editor mode with the Up/Down cursor keys, edit the history and then resend the result string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to use the [mono/LineEditor](https://github.com/mono/LineEditor), how kunif said in the comments. A other way is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;
            // mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r";     // implement this if you use "string indata = sp.ReadLine();" in event handler
            mySerialPort.Open();

            //if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            //{
            //    mySerialPort.Write("\r");
            //}

            List<string> Commands = new List<string>();
            string command = "";
            int counter = 0;
            //mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo consoleInput = Console.ReadKey();

                if (consoleInput.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    Commands.Add(command);
                    counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    //mySerialPort.Write(command + "\r");
                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    command = "";
                }
                else if (consoleInput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    if ((counter >= 0) && (counter < Commands.Count))
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                        Console.Write(Commands[counter]);
                    }

                    if (counter > 0)
                    {
                        counter--;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    command += consoleInput.KeyChar.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();      // it might be better to use --> string indata = sp.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(indata);
        }

        private static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the code without the serial communication. The serial communication should work if you clear my comments.